# How to grab a picture from a Surface

Tags: android, surface

I am pretty new to Android so I hope I can get some directions here.
I have a 360 camera running on Android 7.0. It includes a SDK to get access to the live stitched images. In this SDK there is a function to set a Surface where the output from the stitched images will be directed to.
This is the function provided by the SDK:

`public static void SDK.setSurface(Surface inputSurface)`

I want to grab an image from that surface every second.
How do I create the right kind of Surface? And how do I grab images from this Surface?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I found the answer I might share it here too.
I have create a class which works like a charm. This is what I used:

```
class Capture: ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener{

private var mImageReader: ImageReader? = null
private var mThreadHandler: HandlerThread? = null

fun start() {
    if (!init) {
        if (mImageReader != null) {
            mImageReader?.close()
            mImageReader = null
        }
        if (mThreadHandler != null) {
            mThreadHandler?.quitSafely()
            mThreadHandler = null
        }
        mThreadHandler = HandlerThread("prev")
        mThreadHandler?.start()
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 5)
        mImageReader?.setOnImageAvailableListener(this, Handler(mThreadHandler?.getLooper()))

        SDK.setSurface(if (mImageReader == null) null else mImageReader?.getSurface())
        init = true
    }
}

override fun onImageAvailable(reader: ImageReader) {
    val image = reader.acquireLatestImage()
    val height = image.height
    val stride = image.planes[0].rowStride / image.planes[0].pixelStride
    captureCallback(
        stride,
        height,
        image.timestamp,
        image.planes[0].buffer
    )
    image.close()
}


fun stop() {
    if (init) {
        if (mImageReader != null) {
            mImageReader!!.close()
            mImageReader = null
        }
        if (mThreadHandler != null) {
            mThreadHandler!!.quitSafely()
            mThreadHandler = null
        }
        SDK.setSurface(null)
    }
    init = false
}

fun captureCallback(width: Int, Height: Int, timestamp: Long, data: ByteBuffer) {
    // do something with data
}
```

}
`